# Does the science bonus of multiple scientists stack?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

A kerbal of the Scientist class who gained a few levels gives you a percentual bonus to all science collected by the vessel he is on. What happens when you have multiple scientists on board? Do their bonuses stack or is only the bonus of the best scientist used?

Comment: My boredom will likely lead to me trying some career mode experiment today for it if it's not answered by then. It;s annoying that everyone is level 5 in science mode and you can't cheat levels.

Comment: @Tarkenfire Considering that this question wasn't answered for three weeks now, it's unlikely someone will beat you to it.

Comment: I suppose that is true.

Comment: Just realized that I can test it in science mode because if I disprove the stacking, then it by elimination means that it would be best-scientist picked for the bonus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be the best scientist that is used.

To test this, I made a copy of a save file in which I had 3 kerbals that were scientists, each of different levels.  In the first copy of the save file, I made a craft with 3 spaces in the cockpit, and put those 3 scientists in, and proceeded to do experiments around the KSC.  In the other save, I took the same craft, only putting the scientist in it who was the highest level, and did the same experiments.  The science gains were the same, so it would seem that is how Kerbal Space Program figures the bonus.
It could possibly have been a fluke, it would be best to try to get some more data points, I'll do some more testing tonight or tomorrow to be sure.
After further testing, I have confirmed this.

Comment: Thank you for describing your test method more detailed. I will wait with accepting this answer until you added your results from tonight.

Comment: If the wiki is to be believed, this is now moot since there is no bonus at all.